# YII sanitize input by get parameter

Tags: php, validation, yii

I am working in yii1. I want to edit a record on the based of id(primary key), and passes id inf the form of query string from one page to another. Now I want to sanitize that id on controller where I receive id.
I use `filter_input()` but it cant work.

```
public function actionEditStudentById()
{
    try
    {
        $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        echo $id;
        die();

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $model = StudentDetail::getStudentById($id);

        if (!$model) throw new Exception;

        if(isset($_POST['StudentDetail']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['StudentDetail'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                $model->save(FALSE);
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('update', "Record updated successfully!");
                $this->redirect(['student/list']);
            }
        }
        $this->render('_form',array('model'=>$model));
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Invalid user id: user not available';
    }
}
```

Here `die()` is just used to stop the code. Just before `die()` id is always null. I want that id is always be a number and not any symbol allows in url

Comment: What does your  `getStudentById()` method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Why don't you use int before your id

Cast your string to an `integer` explicitly

```
 $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Ya! that's also working, thanks! If there is another problem related to this, then I'll ask you later

Comment: @PalashGupta if it does then mark it your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with a similar problem at work today and thought I would add my findings. I'm updating an application that uses Yii 1.1 and I was trying to check a flag but `filter_input` was always failing. I ended up adding the following to the program to try and figure out what was going on.

```php
if(isset($_GET['m']))
{
    error_log("GET['m'] = " . var_export($_GET['m'], true));
}

$bFiltered = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'm', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
error_log('Filtered = ' . var_export($filtered, true));
```

The output to the error log was as follows:

```
GET['m'] = 'true'
Filtered = NULL
```

According to the PHP manual entry for [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), null is returned if the named value does not exist.

I can't confirm this but I think Yii is manipulating the `$_GET` and `$_POST` globals and that is breaking the internal pointer used by the filter functions within PHP. You can replicate the issue without Yii by doing the following:

```php
$_GET['test'] = "true";
echo 'Raw value = ' . var_export($_GET['test'], true) . '<br>';

$bFiltered = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'test', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
echo 'Filtered value = ' . var_export($bFiltered, true) . '<br>';
```

This produces the following output:

```
Raw value = 'true'
Filtered value = NULL
```

A potential solution is to use `filter_var` directly on the $_GET variable instead, this gives you access to the same functionality as `filter_input` and doesn't suffer from the same issue as `filter_input`. See the PHP manual entry for [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for more information.

Using the simple example from above:

```php
$_GET['test'] = "true";
echo 'Raw value = ' . var_export($_GET['test'], true) . '<br>';

$bFiltered = filter_var($_GET['test'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
echo 'Filtered value = ' . var_export($bFiltered, true) . '<br>';
```

Produces the following output:

```
Raw value = 'true'
Filtered value = true
```

The downside to this is that you have to remember to wrap it in an `isset()` test just in case the value isn't available.

For example:

```php
if (isset($_GET['test']))
{
   $bFiltered = filter_var($_GET['test'],
                           FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,
                           array('options' => array('default' => false)));
}
else
{
    $bFiltered = false;
}
```